# Stuck at dpkg and can't upgrade anymore

Tags: dpkg

```
gaith@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem. 
gaith@ubuntu:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up update-notifier-common (0.126) ...
flashplugin-installer: downloading http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flashplugin_11.2.202.262.orig.tar.gz
```

after this last message `flashplugin-installer: downloading http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flashplugin_11.2.202.262.orig.tar.gz`I waited for 15 minutes and nothing happened what can I do to fix this problem?

P.S: adobe.com is blocked in my country if this is related to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but once I tried it again, the install went through in about 5 min.